# WindowsForm application with IdentityServer3

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect, identityserver3

I have a few web applications validating against and IdentityServer3 implementation. All of the web applications can do SSO.

Unfortunately, I still have some legacy WinForms apps hanging around. I've been tasked with getting them to integrate with the SSO. I understand how to authenticate the apps against IdentityServer, but how do I get them to interact with the SSO if the user is already logged into one of the webapps?

Comment: Why not look at the WinForms sample we have?

Comment: I assume you are referring to https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples. If you are, I haven't been able to figure out which sample works with WinForms. If there is another place the sample lives at, please let me know

Comment: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients but looking they're all WPF. Here's a WinForms for one of our IdentityModel helper libraries: https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/tree/master/WinForms